# How to create an array with values along specified axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

[`numpy.full()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) is a great function which allows us to generate an array of specific shape and values. For example,

```
>>>np.full((2,2),[1,2])
array([[1,2],
       [1,2]])
```

However, it does not have a built-in option to apply values along a specific axis. So, the following code would not work:

```
>>>np.full((2,2),[1,2],axis=0)
array([[1,1],
       [2,2]])
```

Hence, I am wondering how I can create a 10x48x271x397 multidimensional array with values [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] inserted along axis=0? In other words, an array with [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] repeated along the first dimensional axis. Is there a way to do this using numpy.full() or an alternative method?

```
#Does not work, no axis argument in np.full()
values=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
np.full((10, 48, 271, 397), values, axis=0)
```

Comment: `np.full` supports broadcasting: `np.full((2,2),[[1],[2]])` for your first example. So `np.full((10, 48, 271, 397), np.array(values)[:,None,None,None])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: adding ideas from Michael Szczesny

```py
import numpy as np

shape = (10, 48, 271, 397)
root = np.arange(shape[0])
```

You can use [`np.full`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) or [`np.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) (only get a view at creation time):

```py
arr1 = np.broadcast_to(root, shape[::-1]).T
arr2 = np.full(shape[::-1], fill_value=root).T

%timeit np.broadcast_to(root, shape[::-1]).T
%timeit np.full(shape[::-1], fill_value=root).T

# 3.56 µs ± 18.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
# 75.6 ms ± 243 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

And instead of getting the shape backwards and the array backwards again, you can use singleton dimension, but it seems less generalizable:

```py
root = root[:, None, None, None]

arr3 = np.broadcast_to(root, shape)
arr4 = np.full(shape, fill_value=root)

root = np.arange(shape[0])
%timeit root_ = root[:, None, None, None]; np.broadcast_to(root_, shape)
%timeit root_ = root[:, None, None, None]; np.full(shape, fill_value=root_)

# 3.61 µs ± 6.36 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
# 57.5 ms ± 114 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Checks that everything is equal and actually what we want:

```py
assert arr1.shape == shape

for i in range(shape[0]):
    sub = arr1[i]
    assert np.all(sub == i)

assert np.all(arr1 == arr2)
assert np.all(arr1 == arr3)
assert np.all(arr1 == arr4)
```

Comment: This is 6120x faster than `np.full` on my machine because it's a read-only view of *root*. But if you only need a view, it is a very nice solution. On the other hand, 5164176 pointers referencing the same element seems to have a rather limited field of application.